# Django form is saying field is required despite providing value

Tags: django

I have a form with a required field `customer_phone_number` and despite passing a phone number in with the data the form isn't valid..

Submitting the form through a view works but not in the shell.

```
class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Order
        fields = (
            'date',
            'customer_phone_number',
        )
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['customer_phone_number'].required = True
        self.fields['customer_phone_number'].widget = PhoneNumberPrefixWidget()

data = {
    'date': '2020-04-20',
    'customer_phone_number': '+17168567800',
}
form = OrderForm(data=data)
form.is_valid()
print(form.errors)  # {'customer_phone_number': ['This field is required.']}
```

The only thing I can think of is that I'm using a custom widget but I have no idea how to correct this error.

```
from phonenumber_field.phonenumber import PhoneNumber

from django.forms import Select, TextInput
from django.forms.widgets import MultiWidget


class PhonePrefixSelect(Select):
    initial = '+1'

    def __init__(self, attrs=None):
        choices = [('+1', '+1')]
        super().__init__(attrs, choices=sorted(choices, key=lambda item: item[1]))

    def render(self, name, value, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().render(
            name, value or self.initial, *args, **kwargs)


class PhoneNumberPrefixWidget(MultiWidget):
    """
    A Widget that splits phone number input into:
    - a country select box for phone prefix
    - an input for local phone number
    """

    def __init__(self, attrs=None):
        widgets = (
            PhonePrefixSelect(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control w-25 mr-2',
                'tabindex': '-1'
            }),
            TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control w-75'
            }),
        )
        super().__init__(widgets, attrs)

    def decompress(self, value):
        if value:
            if type(value) == PhoneNumber:
                if value.country_code and value.national_number:
                    return ["+%d" % value.country_code, value.national_number]
            else:
                return value.split('.')
        return [None, ""]

    def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name):
        values = super().value_from_datadict(
            data, files, name)
        if all(values):
            return '%s.%s' % tuple(values)
        return ''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by splitting `customer_phone_number` into two fields: `customer_phone_number_0` and `customer_phone_number_1`